# Given the current situation, what currently available Bitcoin clients are the most likely to follow the longest chain one month from now?

Tags: blockchain-fork

I am completely lost with the various BIPs and what exactly every client implements. So given the current situation as of July 2017, what currently available Bitcoin clients are the most likely to follow the longest chain by end of August?

Comment: What do you mean by "longest chain"? All Bitcoin nodes always follow the "longest **valid** chain". The past disputes are about what to consider "valid".

Comment: @Murch: every client follows the longest valid change according to their own rules. However, since a hard fork is likely, their will be multiple valid chains for different clients. I'm asking what the longest one will be, or more specifically, which client(s) will follow it.

Comment: What does 'longest chain' mean if you don't qualify according to which validity rules?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what will happen, therefore it is hard to say which client will be on "the longest chain".

- Core is scool with bip141, so it will follow that.
- Segwit2x hard fork will be using BTC1.
- USAF could hard fork as well so that client will be for that chain.
- BItmain's BitcoinABC will have their own client (I'm not sure what that client will be/is called).

Comment: Well I was hoping that with the support expressed in blocks, someone who understands what is going might be able to make an educated guess, or at least give some information about the likeliness that each chain will "win".

Comment: What does 'winning' mean? The point of a fork is that there will be two chains. According to Bitcoin nodes, the Bitcoin chain will one. According to S2X nodes, the S2X chain will win.